# Where Exists SQL

Tags: mysql

Though I'm really not sure how to do this, I gave SQL a condition and am trying to add another condition if X doesn't exist, select, say, B. simply if x exist select A and if not exist then select B

Hope this makes senses

```
SELECT * 
FROM [x]
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * from [x] WHERE FileName = 'xxxx')
AND FileName = 'xxxx'
```

thanks

Comment: so what is your question? you can have a look at the guide on how to ask questions:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thta code will produce an error, mysql can't escape names that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM x
WHERE FileName = 'xxx'
  OR (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM x WHERE Filename = 'xxx')
    AND
    whatever the condition is for B
  )
```

Comment: Thank you Richard Barraclough very much, works perfectly